# Showing particular region of texture on GLControl - openTK

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, opentk

I have to show a selected region of image on my Glcontrol. For that I have two variables LeftSideVal and RightSideVal. LeftSideVal is in the range of 0 to 0.5 and RightSideVal is in the range of 0.5 to 1.0.

If I set the LeftSideVal =0.3 and RightSideVal=0.8 then I have to show the region between 0.3 and 0.8 on GLControl with full of it's size (viewport).

I have tried like below. But it is not working properly. Shows some blurred area when changing the values.

```
  GL.Viewport(new Rectangle(0, 0, glControl.Width, glControl.Height));
```

===Shader Code===

```
  if( vTexCoord.x >=LeftSideVal && vTexCoord.x <=RightSideVal){      
  vec4 color=texture2D (sTexture, vec2(vTexCoord.x+LeftSideVal,vTexCoord.y)); 
  gl_FragColor=color;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range [left side val, right side val] is the range of texture coordinates to show over the whole screen. So you need to map that.

In your shader usw

```
float s = LeftSideVal + vTexCoord.x*(RightSideVal-LeftSideVal);
texture(sTexture, vec2(s, vTexCoord.y));
```

Strictly speaking that texture coordinate transformation can be represented by another matrix multiplication. The generalized version would be

```
uniform mat3 T;

/* ... */

texture(sTexture, (T*vec2(vTexCoord,1).xy)
```

where T is set to the appropriate transformation matrix that represents this transformation in 2D.

Comment: Now, LeftSideVal + vTexCoord.x*(RightSideVal-LeftSideVal) is correctly showing the selected area. But it's aspect ratio is missing. Can I correct it on viewport?

Comment: @user2431727: Well, to retain the aspect ratio you'll have to do the same mapping in the y direction i.e. with some `BottomSideVal` and `TopSideVal`. And with those in place you have to calculate their values from the viewport aspect. Essentially you want `(RightSideVal-LeftSideVal)/(TopSideVal-BottomSideVal) == viewport_width/viewport_height`.

Comment: Can I able to flip it? When doing like texture(sTexture, vec2(1.0 - s, vTexCoord.y))-  some portions are missing

Comment: @user2431727 if you do `1-x` so far you're flipping only the image you're cutting your subsection from. You'll also have do the flip inside the mapping calculation then. However what this boils down to (and is the result if you simplify the expressions) is simply swapping the left and right coordinates (or top and bottom) before they go through the mapping. So the calculation turns into `s = RightSideVal - vTexCoord.x*(RightSideVal-LeftSideVal);`. – in the long run it helps developing some intuition for these things. I recommend you toy around with how each term effects the visual outcome.